# Can I export basic entities User etc?

Tags: jhipster

Is it possible to use the 'jhipster export-jdl ' command to also export the 'base' entities e.g. User, Authority etc ?

The reason I ask is because I would like to use JDL studio to create a ManyToOne from one of my own entities to User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export relationships with 'base entities' but not 'base entities' themselves.

However, you can create relationships with these entities even if you have not declared them in your model and, then, generate the relationships of your model in a normal way.

You'd just have to do something like this in your .jh file.

```
entity Bird {
  name String required,
  colour String,
  ...
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Bird{user} to User
}
```

And then,

```
jhipster import-jdl your-jdl-file.jh.
```